# What is "stackoverflow14.com"?

Tags: discussion, copycat-sites

I found that while browsing on my phone and noticed that the formatting was a bit off: the site wasn't a mobile version; it was the desktop site. When I checked the URL, I also noticed that I was on `stackoverflow14.com`, not `stackoverflow.com`.

I also wasn't logged in, which I should be, since I was on other open tabs, so it doesn't seem like it is a different server of Stack Overflow.

Appending other numbers before the tld doesn't seem to work (at least 13 and 15).

It has no ratings on [WOT](https://www.mywot.com/en/scorecard/stackoverflow14.com), which is vastly different than [Stack Overflow's rating](https://www.mywot.com/en/scorecard/stackoverflow.com).

When you click the <kbd>Log In</kbd> button, it redirects you to the official Stack Overflow.

Comment: So it is not affiliated?

Comment: It's not affiliated, isn't giving proper attribution, and is violating copyright law with its use of the logo and site design. You can report it with the "contact us" link in the footer of this page.